# Boot.img and Recovery.img is 0 bytes (size)

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, nandroid

I have a low end android device running on Gingerbread 2.3.5. I am about using it to do some test and customizing my ROM.

I did a Nandroid backup to be on a safe side in case things go wrong. After the backup I noticed my boot image file and recovery image file are both having 0 byte size. I used [Online Nandroid Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.onnandbup).

What could have gone wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe your SDCard was full, or at least didn't provide enough space to store the images? I never used *Online Nandroid Backup*, so I don't know: could it be it requires a custom ROM with Nandroid support?